# Why doesn't SpringBoot Security return any response to REST client although the authentication is done

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I'm trying to implement JWT auth with a REST API in SpringBoot. When I debug my code, I see that the JWT Authenticator works correctly but I can't see that the JWT Authorization code is called by the Spring Security framework and there's no response sent to my REST client. Below are some parts of my code that I think are related to my problem.

I think my request is getting lost somewhere in the Spring Security flow...

`WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
      }
```

`JWTAuthenticationFilter`:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {


  public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (!HttpMethod.POST.matches(request.getMethod())) {
      throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
          "Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
    }

    try {
      JsonAuthenticationParser auth =
          new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), JsonAuthenticationParser.class);
      System.out.println(auth.username);
      System.out.println(auth.password);
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest =
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.username, auth.password);

      return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn("Auth failed!!!!!!!!!!!!");
      throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Could not parse authentication payload");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
      FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
        .claim("roles", ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getAuthorities())
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes()).compact();
    res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    System.out.println("Token:"+token);
  }
```

`JWTAuthorizationFilter`

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

  public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(authManager);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++AUTHERIZATION doFilterInternal++++++++++++++++++++++");

  }

  private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++AUTHERIZATION getAuthentication++++++++++++++++++++++");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Background

When you add a filter to the filter chain without specifying the order (`http.addFilter(...)`), the comparator `HttpSecurity` uses to determine its order in the chain looks at the filter's parent class. `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` comes before `BasicAuthenticationFilter` (see [FilterComparator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterComparator.java)).

The request comes in, reaches `JWTAuthenticationFilter`, and "ends" in the `successfulAuthentication()` method.

## Solution

Continue the filter chain in `JWTAuthenticationFilter`:

```java
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
                                FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) 
                                   throws IOException, ServletException {

    // ...

    chain.doFilter(req, res);

}
```

Comment: thanks, after calling chain.doFilter method, SpringBoot calls the JWTAuthorizationFilter but it returns forbidden(http 403) to my client...

Comment: Are you using credentials for a user with the ADMIN role (since that's what you specified in the config)?